# Empirical verification of the probability integral transform

Tags: r, distributions, normal-distribution, simulation, cumulative-distribution-function

I just discovered when working on Copulae that it was common knowledge that if $X$ is a continuous random variable with probability density function $F_{X}$, then $Y=F_{X}(x)$ follows a uniform distribution.

Before finding the [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform) online I was trying to empirically verify the above statement in R, but couldn't seem to succeed. Could someone please tell me what is wrong in my approach? In the code below I am plotting the histograms (empirical PDFs) of $10^3$ values sampled from the Normal CDF and of $10^3$ values sampled from the Cauchy CDF. Instead of observing uniform distributions, here is what I am getting:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(pnorm(ppoints(1e3)))
hist(pcauchy(ppoints(1e3)))
```

[image]

I was not expecting perfectly uniform distributions, but $10^3$ values should be enough to at least approach something that looks uniform. So what is wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "sampled from the Normal **and** Cauchy CDFs.  One set of points cannot be sampled from both.  `ppoints` seems to be a built in function, but I don't really understand its documentation.

Comment: It was clear from my code. But anyway, I edited my question for clarity. Thanks.

Comment: R has so many built in functions that it's often not clear to me what is a variable name that someone has assigned but not provided, and what is a built in I've never heard of.

Comment: You're not generating random variables. See `rnorm`.

Comment: `ppoints` creates a grid on $[0,1]$ on which to evaluate functions that have support on $[0,1]$ such as CDFs

Comment: ppoints (roughly speaking) generates expected uniform quantiles, not normal (or whatever) random numbers

Comment: Thanks. What misled me is that in the documentation for [pnorm](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Normal.html) it is said that the argument $q$ that should be passed is a vector of quantiles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe your code just does not do what you want it to do.  Here's what you want:

```
set.seed(154)
x <- rnorm(10000)
hist(pnorm(x))
```

This histogram looks uniform.

I believe

```
plot(ppoints(1000), pnorm(ppoints(1000)))
```

results in a plot of a portion of the graph of the normal cdf.

Here's a quick verification

```
plot((1:100 - 50)/25, pnorm((1:100 - 50)/25)) 
points(ppoints(25), pnorm(ppoints(25)), col="blue")
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Yep, That's the way to do it. More generally `p<thing>(r<thing>(n))` will be uniform for some distribution <thing> and sample size n.

Comment: thanks. What misled me is that in the documentation for [`pnorm`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Normal.html) it is said that the argument $q$ that should be passed is a vector of quantiles.

Comment: @Glen_b That looks like C++ template.

Comment: @Antoine the normal use case for `pnorm` is when you want to use it to get the probabilty associated with a quantile, but you're using it as a transformation.